# Как выделить View

Tags: java, android

Есть ScrollView  в который я добавляю View, мне нужно для этих View иметь возможность выделить вложенный элемент (TextView). Я сделал селектор, он реагирует на нажатие, и меняет цвет, но когда я отпускаю его - он принимает прежний вид (цвет) .
Вопрос:  как сохранить элемент в "нажатом" состоянии?

**item_in_scroll_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMsgFrom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_massage_slector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorRed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorRed" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/bg_message_from"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Пробовали добавить `android:checable="true"` для `TextView` и `android:state_checked="true"` в селектор?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал, получил ошибку android:checable="true", говорит что нету такого аттрибута.

Comment: А если `clickable`?

Comment: Да, clickable нужно тоже было включить, без него не работало!

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему добавлением нужного состояния android:state_selected="true" в selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorRed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorRed" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <!-- selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/actionBar_yellow" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/bg_message_from"/>
</selector>
```

И в коде добавил listener для TextView:

```
    txtMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtMsg.setSelected(!txtMsg.isSelected());
        }
    });
```

код TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_massage_slector"/>
```